# 'Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.PersistChildrenAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web,

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have create a crystal report template in asp.net window form and then  i'm adding crystal report template in asp.net core web project then getting this error. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Which version of .net framework do  you use?

Comment: .net core framework 3.1

Comment: You can refer to [the official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.persistchildrenattribute?view=netframework-4.8),PersistChildrenAttribute is in .net framwork,not in .net core,so you cannot use ` [PersistChildrenAttribute]` in .net core.

Comment: Thanks @YiyiYou .But i want to create crystal reports in .net core .Have any way to create please help me?

Comment: Crystal Reports does not support .NET Core.You can use it in  .Net rather than .net core project.

Comment: My project requirement  in .net core that's why we build crystal reports in core.